# Having sounds complete before the next, in python?

Tags: python, loops, audio, tkinter, pygame

In Python/pygame, I desire to repeat a certain wav file (read by `pygame.mixer.Sound("foo.wav").play()` in a loop, and have them play one after another, preferably after last has completed or by a default delay (1500ms works)

So far, paraphrasing, I have this:

```
    for x in range(0, 5):
        pygame.mixer.Sound("foo.wav").play()
```

When it plays, however, it plays all at once.

Using pygame.time for a delay hangs the window, as does tkinter .after(1500), and I cannot seem to find a straight-forward means to do this with either libraries or python or even an example of something playing a few tones with delay as I intend. I could substitute pygame with a more 'standard' audio drop-in for Python, or potentially use threading if it comes to it for the button presses, if it requires hackery to do such a thing with the pygame mixer alone.

Some handy references if needed:
http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html
https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html

Answer (score 3):

The most straightforward way to do this seems to be to get the length of each sound and play the next one after the given time has elapsed, via Tkinter's `after` method.

```
self.sound_queue = [pygame.mixer.Sound(s) for s in ('foo.wav', 'bar.ogg', 'baz.mp3')]

def play_queue(self, q, num=0)
    sound = q[num]
    duration = int(sound.get_length() * 1000)
    sound.play()
    if num < len(q)-1:
        self.root.after(duration, self.play_queue, q, num+1)

self.play_queue(self.sound_queue)
```

You could also look at [`pygame.mixer.Channel.queue()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Channel.queue) and [`pygame.mixer.Channel.set_endevent`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Channel.set_endevent), as those are probably the intended way to do this sort of thing.